# Better way to access tuple(other than match case)

Tags: scala

I have this code.  The method returns a (User, Acl, Tree) tuple.  Instead of accessing the data with `_._1, _._2` etc I use match.  Is there an easier(better) way then what I'm doing?  Thanks

```
    User.findUserJoinAclTree(3).map {

        _ match {

            case(user, acl, tree) =>

                Logger.info(user.email)
                Logger.info(acl.id)
                Logger.info(tree.name)

        }                   

    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your expression can be simplified a bit:

```
User.findUserJoinAclTree(3) map {
  case (user,_,_) => Logger.info(user.email)
}
```

First, you don't need to match the arguments, you can directly pass a partial function to map, then you can use wildcard (_) for the the tuple elements you don't need

Answer (score 5):

In this particular case,

```
for ((user,_,_) <- User.findUserJoinAclTree(3)) yield Logger.info(user.email)
```